# How to find lowest RSE and highest DC and NPI values in the data frame

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame with 245 observations. There are 4 columns; id, RSE, DC and NPI. What I want to find is id with the lowest RSE and highest DC,NPI. I need to find which id is the best possible answer. Here is the first 6 rows of my data. id, RSE, DC, NPI.
\

```
1   2.5 4.15    0.350
2   3.9 5.35    0.350
3   3.8 5.25    0.475
4   3.2 5.40    0.425
5   2.7 4.80    0.350
6   2.8 4.70    0.175
```

This is the first six rows of my data frame. I don't know how to write R code for that. I think which.max and which.min won't work.

I don't know how to get it. I tried like 10% of the lowest scores. But it generates only ids.